# Matplotlib animation - tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate, tuples

having issues with the FuncAnimantion function in matplotlib. Code is as follows:

```
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from ppbase import *

plt.ion()

#This is just essentially a stream of data
Paramater = PbaProObject("address of object")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,2), ylim=(-90, 90))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
  line.set_data([], [])
  return line, 

def animate(Parameter):
  x = time.time()
  y = Parameter.ValueStr
  line.set_data(x, y)
  return line, 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate(Parameter), init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=2, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1203, in _on_timer
ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 876, in _step
still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 735, in _step self._draw_frame(framedata)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 754, in _draw_next_frame self._draw_frame(framedata, self._blit)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1049, in _draw_frame self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Been reading around all morning and it seems commonly plt.plot is overwritten by a tuple, so I checked for that but don't think I have done it anywhere. I've also turned blit to false but that didn't help either. I do also want to interactively update the x-axis, I had line:
    ax = plt.axes(xlim((x-10), (x+10)), ylim=(-90, 90)) 
in the animate function but took that out to see if it made any difference.

I think mostly the problems stem from not really understanding tuples too well. Also my understanding of the FuncAnimation function is that it calls the animate() each time it updates the plot - hence why I though that I could use it to update the axis' also. But this may not be the case.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try replacing `return line,` by `return line`

Comment: "`a,`" is shorthand for "`(a,)`" - i.e. it's a tuple of length 1.

Comment: Changed that and I get the same error but the last bit is now: TypeError: 'line2D' object is not callable

Comment: Ah! but this is another question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have googled around for this new error and still cannot work out what might be wrong, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the function *object* not the result of the calling the function and you can pass a generator to `frames` (this might only work on 1.4.0+).

```
# turn your Parameter object into a generator
def param_gen(p):
    yield p.ValueStr

def animate(p):
    # get the data the is currently on the graph
    old_x = line.get_xdata()
    old_y = line.get_ydata()
    # add the new data to the end of the old data
    x = np.r_[old_x, time.time()]
    y = np.r_[old_y, p]
    # update the data in the line
    line.set_data(x, y)
    # return the line2D object so the blitting code knows what to redraw
    return line, 


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=param_gen(Parameter), interval=2, blit=True)
```

I also fixed a problem with your animation function and you should use 4 space indents, not 2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain what your changes do and why you have suggested them? I would like to fully understand the reason so I can fix my own problems in future. My program still does not work, I get a TypeError: Unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. I feel i'm getting closer though, so understanding this fix may help me. What is the purpose of np.r_ ?